# Moba Xterm removes folder structure when dragging and dropping a folder into SFTP panel

Tags: sftp, mobaxterm

If i drag a folder into MobaXterm it copies the files across sftp into the directory leaving out any folders that existed and just copying all files into the folder.

Is there any way to change this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems to follow a specific case. If I drag from my "desktop" to the remote box, things are fine. But if I drag from a network directory (via Moba running on my box) to the remote box, the flattening you describe happens. I don't know of an actual "*configuration fix*", but the work-around is to drag (using File Explorer, not Moba) from the network directory, to your machine, then use Moba to drag from there to the remote box.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that sometimes it doesn't happen but couldn't quite work out why. Yeah seems you are right however that is good to know. Wish they could improve on this however still find myself going to FileZilla just cause of this occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're supposed to enable the "follow terminal folder" checkbox in order to follow file directory structure. Disabling that checkbox causes the copied folder to ignore any of its inner folders.